# Cannot properly size Frame with scrollbar to lets say full width of screen

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

my problem is that i cannot properly size the frame of my program content to full width of screen or change it at all. All i get is a large root window with a small window anchored top left of it with my content in it. But i want my content to be able to be very long which possibly would go from side of display to the other side.

````
from tkinter import *
def update_scrollregion(event):
    photoCanvas.configure(scrollregion=photoCanvas.bbox("all"))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1700x900")   

#i tried to change the width below without success, it doesnt change anything either gets smaller nor bigger
photoFrame = Frame(root, width=250, height=190, bg="#EBEBEB")
photoFrame.grid()
photoFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
photoFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 

photoCanvas = Canvas(photoFrame, bg="#EBEBEB")
photoCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

canvasFrame = Frame(photoCanvas, bg="#EBEBEB")
photoCanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=canvasFrame, anchor='nw')

txt=Text(canvasFrame, height=2, width=30)
Button(canvasFrame, text="Button1", borderwidth=0, bg="#EBEBEB").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
txt.insert(INSERT, "imagine a very long text here which should stretch from the left side of my screen to the right side of it")  
txt.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

photoScroll = Scrollbar(photoFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
photoScroll.config(command=photoCanvas.yview)
photoCanvas.config(yscrollcommand=photoScroll.set)
photoScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

canvasFrame.bind("<Configure>", update_scrollregion)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Your code does not run.

Comment: Sorry forgot the text method. Should be fine right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add .. root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) and root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) and set photoFrame.grid(sticky=NSEW).

```
from tkinter import *

def update_scrollregion(event):
    photoCanvas.configure(scrollregion=photoCanvas.bbox("all"))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1700x900")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#i tried to change the width below without success, it doesnt change anything either gets smaller nor bigger
photoFrame = Frame(root, width=250, height=190, bg="#EBEBEB")
photoFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
photoFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
photoFrame.grid(sticky=NSEW)

photoCanvas = Canvas(photoFrame, bg="#EBEBEB")
photoCanvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
photoCanvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
photoCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

canvasFrame = Frame(photoCanvas, bg="#EBEBEB")
canvasFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
canvasFrame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
canvasFrame.grid(sticky=NSEW)

photoCanvas.create_window(0, 0, window=canvasFrame, anchor='nw')

# txt = Text(canvasFrame, height=2, width=30)
txt = Text(canvasFrame)
txt.insert(INSERT, "imagine a very long text here which should stretch from the left side of my screen to the right side of it, imagine a very long text here which should stretch from the left side of my screen to the right side of it")
txt.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=NSEW)

Button(canvasFrame, text="Button1", borderwidth=0, bg="#EBEBEB").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

photoScroll = Scrollbar(photoFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
photoScroll.config(command=photoCanvas.yview)
photoCanvas.config(yscrollcommand=photoScroll.set)
photoScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

canvasFrame.bind("<Configure>", update_scrollregion)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what these options mean and why to add them?

Comment: @abdussamed17:  Here is a link where you can find all the info explaining 
 rowconfigure and columnconfigure. https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html